# Will this switch do what I require?

Tags: switch

I'm a complete network newbie, so please forgive any egregious errors.

I'm a Master's student who wishes to perform benchmarks on distributed databases.

Firstly, I wish to set up configurations locally and ultimately run these systems on various cloud providers.

I was recommended [this switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M1C0186), but on reading [this review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1OQ4VGLSX4ZOS/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00M1C0186#R1OQ4VGLSX4ZOS), it says:

> - The management controller, integrated within the BCM53128 is a weak CPU derived from the 1980s-vintage, 8-bit Intel 8051, which is easily
>   overloaded. This explains the lack of HTTPS SSL support, occasional
>   dropped HTTP requests, etc. It's actually impressive they managed to
>   squeeze an IP stack and web interface onto such a small CPU at all.

Now, my distributed databases will have to communicate using HTTPS.

I then found [this switch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-GS108UK-Gigabit-Ethernet-Unmanaged/dp/B0000E5SES/ref=asc_df_B0000E5SES/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=232043227663&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17217470537965882944&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007850&hvtargid=pla-385651681862&th=1) and [its review](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-GS108UK-Gigabit-Ethernet-Unmanaged/dp/B0000E5SES/ref=asc_df_B0000E5SES/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=232043227663&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17217470537965882944&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1007850&hvtargid=pla-385651681862&th=1) says:

> - A few very minor "cons": it doesn't support HTTPS (secure) access to the management interface, but this isn't that much of an issue on a
>   private network.

Now, I don't care about HTTPS access to the management interface - ordinary HTTP is fine - security is **not** an issue here. I just want the databases to be able to communicate via HTTPS.

So, my question is if the first router will allow HTTPS comms between my machines (don't care about managment) or is the second router better suited to my needs?

As I've explained, I'm  a newbie, so if I've left out any important information, please let me know. Also, if there are other factors which I haven't considered, please let me know also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any bad/non-existing HTTPS support only refers to the management function of that switch. Traffic on the network, between ports, is just that and it is not going to be impacted in any way by any poor manageability of the switch itself.

> if the first router will allow HTTPS comms between my machines

Note that any traffic between machines in the same subnet doesn't cross your router. *Routers* are only used for communication across subnets. *Switches* on the other hand do not control your local traffic by default. (Some (better) switches support ACLs that allow specific filter, however.)

Provided that all modern switches are *non-blocking*, ie. only limited by port bandwidth, any switch should do what you're asking. (Large, modular switches may be limited by their backplane, but that's another dimension.)

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise input. All the machines (3 in this case - it's  a PoC) will be just attached to the same switch which will itself only be attached to the home broadband router dooh-dah (told you I was a newbie! :-) ), so I'll have no inter-machine comms difficulties? Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are no problems to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and explanation!